# How can i get a variable from request scope in jstl

Tags: jstl

I want to use below code in jstl.

```
String shouldFollow=(String)request.getAttribute("shouldFollow");
```

How can i do so in jstl

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it might do you good to research the difference between [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) and the [Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).

Your line of code can be wrapped in an expression like so:

```
${ shouldFollow }
```

The `PageContext` object will resolve the expression by searching the attribute mapping of the pageContext, request, session, and servletContext scopes respectively given this syntax.

You can use expressions for the values of attributes of JSTL tags:

```
<c:if test="${ shouldFollow }">
    ...
</c:if>
```

Where the body of this tag will execute if `shouldFollow` is true.